# How can I expand a symlinked file path instead of the real file path?

Tags: vimscript

I am editing a file which lives in a directory that is a symlink to another directory, i.e.

```
% ls -alh ~/www/experiments 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu  80 Dec  5 19:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu  60 Dec  8 16:25 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   8 Dec  5 19:52 tmp -> /tmp/web
```

so when I am editing the file:

```
~/www/experiments/tmp/webpage.php
```

Because the parent folder of `webpage.php` ( `tmp` ) is pointing to `/tmp/web`
when I run the vimscript command

```
echo expand('%:p')
```

vim will echo the real file path, i.e.

```
/tmp/web/webpage.php
```

how can I make vim expand the symlinked path in vimscript? i.e. the desired output would be:

```
/home/ubuntu/www/experiments/tmp/webpage.php
```

I've looked in `:h filename-modifiers` and there doesn't seem to be anything about symlinks. Also looked at functions like `resolve()` - unfortunately I think `resolve()` does the opposite of what I want, it produces the real file path.

Comment: I don't there there's an easy way to do this; `getcwd()`and `:pwd` also always return the full path, rather than the symlinked path that the shell's `pwd` command or `$PWD` variable use (In other words, it looks like Vim normalises the path on open).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes, and also linux doesn't allow hardlinking to directories - which might have been able to "fool" vim. I think I have a work around though, I'm just using the `match()` function and an `if` block to detect when the filepath expands to the `/tmp` location, and if so, then `substitute()` to "fix" the path

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but you can mount an NFS directory on the localhost to work around the inability to hardlink directories. On Linux you can also use `mount --bind /src/ /dest`, and on FreeBSD `mount_nullfs /src /dest`. Other systems may have similar constructs (e.g. directory junctions in Windows). Also see: [What is a bind mount?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/33645) at Unix.SE.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks for the info, `mount --bind` definitely looks interesting. I see [what is a bind mount](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) is one of  Gilles' canonical answers. It usually takes me a day or two to get through those! I have finally got this working now anyway. The overall goal is that - when I am working on a webpage code file, and I want to view that files output in a browser, I simply hit a `<Leader>` mapping and vim launches a new browser tab with the corresponding URL for the file.

Answer (score 1):

### Check if a path has a symlink anywhere in it, and if so return 1, otherwise 0

Pseudocode:  Use the shell to convert the symlink path to the path it points to.  If the two paths are identical then it's not a symlink.  Otherwise it is.

```
function! IsPathSymlinkPath(foo)
    "Sorry for the incantations.  Level 9 hax required.
    if ( substitute( 
        \ system('readlink -f ' . 
        \ a:foo), '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\_s*$', '\1', '') == 
        \ substitute(a:foo, '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$', '\1', '') 
        \ )
        return 1
    endif
endfunction

echo IsPathSymlinkPath("/home/el/symlink/somefile")
"returns 1

echo IsPathSymlinkPath("/home/el/normal/somefile")
"returns 0
```

Or you could do it using vimscript's resolve and expand code

```
function! IsSymlinkPath(mypath)
    let resolved_expanded = resolve(expand(a:mypath))
    let trim_and_flatten_path = substitute(
        \ resolved_expanded, '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$', '\1', '')
    let trim_original_mypath  = substitute(
        \ a:mypath, '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$', '\1', '') 
    if ( trim_and_flatten_path == trim_original_mypath )
        return 1
    endif
endfunction
```